# Solution to “#1054 - Unknown column 'c.AssetGroup' in 'on clause'” error?

Tags: mysql

THIS IS MY QUERY

```
SELECT
    a.ClassCode,
    a.Description,
    d.BusinessUnit,
    d.BUDes,
    d.Department,
    c.Total
FROM tbl_fa_asset_reg_mas_b_class a
    JOIN tbl_fa_asset_reg_mas_c_group b ON a.ClassCode = b.AssetClass
    JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(c.AssetGroup) AS Total
     FROM tbl_fa_asset_reg c
 GROUP BY c.AssetGroup)c ON c.AssetGroup = b.AssetGroup
JOIN tbl_a_comp_f_bu d ON d.BusinessUnit = c.BusinessUnit
GROUP BY a.ClassCode, a.Description, d.BusinessUnit, d.BUDes, d.Department ORDER BY ClassCode ASC
```

> #1054 - Unknown column 'c.AssetGroup' in 'on clause'

when i run this query

Comment: Fix your title to match the question.

Comment: Your query has too many problems I believe for a simple answer.  You might want to provide a _minimal_ and _reproducible_ sample of the problem which others may try to fix.  The subquery is wrong, and the following join is also wrong.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT a.ClassCode,a.Description,d.BusinessUnit,d.BUDes,d.Department,c.Total
FROM tbl_fa_asset_reg_mas_b_class a
JOIN
tbl_fa_asset_reg_mas_c_group b 
ON a.ClassCode = b.AssetClass
JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(c.AssetGroup)AS Total,AssetGroup 
     FROM tbl_fa_asset_reg c
 GROUP BY c.AssetGroup)c 
ON c.AssetGroup = b.AssetGroup
JOIN tbl_a_comp_f_bu d 
ON d.BusinessUnit = c.BusinessUnit
GROUP BY 
a.ClassCode, a.Description, d.BusinessUnit, d.BUDes, d.Department 
ORDER BY ClassCode ASC
```

Comment: thx. .but when i run #1054 - Unknown column 'c.BusinessUnit' in 'on clause'